# ms access Add, Edit, Delete Items through an Access form

Tags: forms, ms-access, editing, subform

I'm not real familiar with inputting data through forms.  Up until now I've just been handling the data from the table.  However, now I have a table with two pieces of information:
Group   ID
Each ID is in a group, not all IDs are represented in the table (ie there is another table with a complete list of IDs...many to one), and multiple IDs can be associated with the same group.
I want to make a form that allows the user to add a new ID/group row, edit an existing ID's "Group," and delete an existing Row. I want the user to see the changes he/she has made. I think there's a way to show a snapshot of the table as part of the form?  How do I do all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a continuous form? You can use a combo to display additional information for each control/field, if that is required.

EDIT re Comment

From your comments and original post, it seems that what may suit is a main form and subform. The subform can be set to prevent editing - it will display the existing groups. The main form will have your combos and buttons.

As to the various types of form, look at the Views Allowed property for the form, you will find:

- Single Form (suitable for main form)
- Continuous Form (suitable for subform)
- Datasheet

Comment: not real sure what you mean by "continuous form" I tried "tabular view" and it works, but it's not very user friendly.  This has to be used by people who have very little computer savvy and so what i really want is to have two combo boxes:  One for Group and one for ID and then a big button that says ADD and all they ahve to do is put in a new ID and its Group and say ADD. and then i want a list of the current IDs that are in the table and i want them to be able to select one and then click a big DELETE button or a big EDIT button.

Comment: I have added some notes. Have you had a chance to look at some of the sample databases available on the MS website?

Comment: i took little pieces of your suggestions and the other answer and got it working.  I ended up with a form and subform structure where the main form just specified a filter for the sub and using a continuous form for the sub, data was just input straight in the sub form.  thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Link one table (or query) to the main form and your second table (or query) to a sub form.   Drag your sub form onto the main form. Tie the two forms together in properties (sub form) under link master fields and link child fields add the key ID.